# Is there a way to pass value from fastlane lane to gitlab-ci.yml scripts scope?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, fastlane

I want to manually set pipeline stage status to "Warning" if specific thing happens in my fastfile lane. To do so, I need to allow_failure for some exit_code (e.g. 250) and trigger this exit_code from fastlane lane.

But anything I've tried still results in "ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1" in job log. So is there any alternative way, how to tell gitlab-ci.yml that my fastlane lane wants to trigger exit_code 250?

I believe I need something like this in my gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
ciBuild:
  stage: build
  script:
    - fastlane ci_somelane
  allow_failure:
    exit_codes: 250
```

and this in Fastfile:

```
lane :ci_somelane do
// do something, to exit with code 250
end
```

but it still results in "ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1" in job log, that's why condition does not trigger

Comment: Try adding the environment variable `FF_USE_NEW_BASH_EVAL_STRATEGY: "1"` to your job. See if that helps.